# Function overloading: empty parameter list vs parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

```
template <typename T>
void call(T) {  //#1
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename...Args>
void call(T, Args...) {  //#2
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

When I call the function like this

```
call(10);
```

GCC, Clang, and MSVC all use #1.

However, the partial ordering rule in the standard says:

> If the parameter-declaration corresponding to P<sub>i</sub> is a function parameter pack, then the type of its *declarator-id* is compared with each remaining parameter type in the *parameter-type-list* of A. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function parameter pack. During partial ordering, if A<sub>i</sub> was originally a function parameter pack:
>
> - **(10.1) if P does not contain a function parameter type corresponding to A<sub>i</sub> then A<sub>i</sub> is ignored;**
> - **(10.2) otherwise, if P<sub>i</sub> is not a function parameter pack, template argument deduction fails.**

When we deduce #1 from #2, with `T, Args...` as A, `T` as P, P does not contain a template argument corresponding to `Args...`. `Args...` is ignored, so #1 can be deduced from #2 successfully.

Then the deducing #2 from #1, with `T` as A and `T, Args...` as P, also successfully results in `T = T, Args... = {}`.

Therefore, according to the partial ordering rules, when call `call(10)`, the compiler should be giving the ambiguous error, but in fact all compiler called #1, why is this?

Comment: you have to escape `<>` with single quotes inside text, otherwise it is not visible, fixed that for you, but not sure if I missed some

Comment: Isn't #1 a specialization?

Comment: @freakish It's not.  It's a primary template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilers are correct.  `#1` is more specialized than `#2`.

---

The rule for partial ordering template parameter packs is specified in [[temp.deduct.partial]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#8):

> Using the resulting types `P` and `A`, the deduction is then done as
>   described in [temp.deduct.type]. If `P` is a function parameter pack,
>   the type `A` of each remaining parameter type of the argument template
>   is compared with the type `P` of the *declarator-id* of the function
>   parameter pack. Each comparison deduces template arguments for
>   subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the
>   function parameter pack. Similarly, if `A` was transformed from a
>   function parameter pack, it is compared with each remaining parameter
>   type of the parameter template. If deduction succeeds for a given
>   type, the type from the argument template is considered to be at least
>   as specialized as the type from the parameter template.

When the parameter template is `#1` and the argument template is `#2`, the *declarator-id* `Args` (which is a type) from `#2` is compared with each of the remaining parameters in `#1` (there's none).  Therefore, `#2` is at least as specialized as `#1`.

When the parameter template is `#2` and the argument template is `#1`, the *declarator-id* `Args` (which is a type) from `#2` is compared with each of the remaining parameters in `#1` (there's none).  Therefore, `#1` is at least as specialized as `#2`.

Seems ambiguous, right?  Now we have the tie breaker, [[temp.deduct.partial]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#11):

> If, after considering the above, function template `F` is at least as
>   specialized as function template `G` and vice-versa, and if `G` has a
>   trailing parameter pack for which `F` does not have a corresponding
>   parameter, and if `F` does not have a trailing parameter pack, then
>   `F` is more specialized than `G`.

Apparently, `#1` is more specialized than `#2`.